# Reading in grid of characters in C

Tags: c, search, cpu-word

I am working on a word search assignment for my C class. I need to read in a grid of characters from the console by using the redirection operator such as

> ./a.out < data1

I am not reading in the data from a file, so I don't need to use file operations. I need to read this grid in and then store it in a 2D array. However, my code just reads in the first line of the grid and stops. Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    char inputGrid[50][50];
    char solvedGrid[50][50];
    char inputString[50];
    char ch;

    int inputRow = 0;
    int rowLength = 0;
    int i = 0;

    size_t r;
    size_t c;

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputString);
    rowLength = strlen(inputString);

    for (r = 0, c = 0; r <= rowLength; r++) {
        if (inputString[r] == '\n') {
            scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputString);

            inputRow++;

            if (inputString[r] != ' ') {
                inputGrid[inputRow][c] = inputString[r];
                c++;
            }
        } else
        if (inputString[r] != ' ') {
            inputGrid[inputRow][c] = inputString[r];
            c++;
        }
    }

    // Print the array
    for (r = 0; r < strlen(inputString); r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < strlen(inputString); c++) {
            printf("%c", inputGrid[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I need to read in the data in the form of space separated characters that form a square matrix. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop, you increment `r` even though, at most, you have read a single character.  You might find it easier to use *nested loops*: a loop to keep track of the rows/lines, and a loop inside that one to process each character within that row/line.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputString)` doesn't store `\n` in `inputString`, hence the test `inputString[r] == '\n'` will never be true.

You could use

```
    int i, r, c;
    while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputString) > 0)
    {
        for (rowLength = i = 0; i < strlen(inputString); ++i)
            if (inputString[i] != ' ')
                inputGrid[inputRow][rowLength++] = inputString[i];
        if (++inputRow >= rowLength) break;
    }

    // Print the array
    for (r = 0; r < inputRow; ++r, printf("\n"))
        for (c = 0; c < rowLength; ++c)
            printf("%c", inputGrid[r][c]);
```